# Some questions about the compact boson in David Tong's notes on Gauge Theory

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, bosons, duality, compactification

The notes can be found at http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html.

In Sec. 7.5.1, *T-Duality*, around Eq. 7.51, it says that the Bianchi identity $\partial_\mu(\epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)=0$ may not hold. Does this indicate $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi\neq \partial_\nu\partial_\mu\phi$. If so, how can this happen?

In addition, since $\int d^2x$ is an integration over an infinite-long tube, the boundary integration $\oint d x^\mu$ should be over two circles at opposite ends of the tube. Each circle gives a winding number, so the final results will be the difference of the two winding numbers, which is indeed an integer. However, one can continuously move one circle along the tube to the other while the winding number cannot vary in a continual way, so there should be no difference between the two windings, and the integer should always be zero. Where is my argument wrong?

Another question is about how to integrate out the compact boson. I can only try to understand it with a naive analogy $\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \, e^{i\theta a}=\frac{e^{i 2\pi a}\;\;-1}{ia}$, and I fail to make a further step.

Answer (score 1):

> In Sec. 7.5.1, *T-Duality*, around Eq. 7.51, it says that the Bianchi identity $\partial_\mu(\epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)=0$ may not hold. Does this indicate $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi\neq \partial_\nu\partial_\mu\phi$. If so, how can this happen?

Since $\phi$ always lies in the range $[0,2\pi)$ (see Eq 7.50), at places where $\phi$ goes from $2\pi-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$, the derivative will be infinite. In other words, the non-trivial winding prevents the naive Bianchi identify from working.

> However, one can continuously move one circle along the tude to the other while the winding number cannot vary in a continual way, so there should be no difference between the two windings, and the integer should always be zero. Where is my argument wrong?

Let's just take a finite cylinder of length $1$; let $z$ be the coordinate along the height of the cylinder ($0\leq z\leq 1$). At $z=0$ let's say $\phi=0$ (no winding), and at $z=1$ suppose $\phi=2 \theta \mod 2\pi$, where $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ is the angular coordinate along the cylinder (this corresponds to a winding number of $2$). Here is a function on the cylinder that transitions from winding number $0$ at $z=0$ to winding number $2$ at $z=1$
\begin{equation}
\phi(z,\theta) = 2 z \theta \mod 2\pi
\end{equation}
The winding number in fact does change discontinuously as you vary $z$; it changes from $0$ to $1$ at $z=1/2$ and from $1$ to $2$ at the boundary $z=1$.

> Another question is about how to integrate out the compact boson

I don't understand what you are asking here, unfortunately. The propagator is given after Eq 7.58, so you can use that expression as a cross-check when doing a Gaussian path integral over $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. I also considered a similar example before posting the question. I gave up it because φ is not even a continuous function. For example, φ(1/4,2π)=π≠0=φ(1/4,0) (mod 2π) while θ=0 and 2π are the same point. So the winding number is even underfined at most values of z. Assuming this is allowed, then why at boundaries (z=0 and 1) not allowed (or Eq. 7.51 can take non-integer values). For the last question, I need more time to check.

Comment: @A.A.Lee Exactly, $\phi$ is not continuous. You can physically picture $\phi$ as the angular coordinate of a small bug along an extremely small compact dimension (so imagine there the bug's position has three coordinates, $z,\theta,\phi$, instead of $\phi$ being a field living in 2 dimensions). Then it's not surprising that $\phi$ is not continuous. You can also imagine the winding number increases by one every time the bug makes a "lap" of the compact dimension; clearly this quantity can change discontinuously (the "lap number" of a racecar driver discontinuously changes after each lap).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the bug example. Perhaps you want to mean lots of bugs filling at all z and θ? Maybe a better example is from string theory (though I'm not quite familiar with that). Then the function describes a closed string changes its winding through breaking into an open string. What I'm still puzzled is, why an open string is allowed as an intermediate state, and not allowed as an initial or final state?

Comment: @A.A.Lee The bug was just meant to be a cute way to mean "trace out the path of a string." But if anything it's probably better to work with strings, since T-duality is more about closed strings. Are you sure the closed string breaks into an open string, instead of two closed strings? (I'm not a string theorist so I'm genuinely asking)

Comment: I'm not very sure. At least from a classical veiwpoint, "φ(z=1/4,θ)=θ/2 mod 2π (Here φ is the string position in a compactified space, θ refers to different points of the string, z is time)" looks nothing like two closed strings.

Comment: @A.A.Lee That's fair, and I am not really sure how to relate the string and field pictures. Well, backing off of the analogy, at a mathematical level (given the definition of $\phi$ as lying in the range $[0,2\pi)$), I don't see any problem with the field being discontinuous as it goes from $2\pi$ to $0$.

Comment: If discontinuity is allowed, periodic boundary condition then makes no difference. So why do we need it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same questions when reading this section of these notes. While it is always true that $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi =0$ if there is a vortex then $\phi$ won't be well defined at that point and so this quantity won't necessarily vanish. Then in this case the loop integral $\oint dx_\mu \partial_\mu \phi$ will say by how much it doesn't vanish by Stokes theorem.

As for integrating out the compact boson, the answer is essentially what you would expect for if $\tilde \phi$ were non-compact: it just sets the coefficeint on $\tilde \phi$ to be zero. Here is a sketch of what I worked out modulo factors of $2\pi$. First we Fourier transform over spatial coordinates (it shouldn't matter here if space is compact or non-compact)
\begin{align}
    Z[\phi] &= \int \mathcal D \tilde \phi \exp\left[{i \int d^2 x \ \tilde \phi \epsilon_{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi}\right]  \\
    &=  \int \mathcal D \tilde \phi \exp \left[i \epsilon_{\mu \nu} \int _k k_\mu k_\nu \tilde \phi(k) \phi(k) \right]
\end{align}
Then consider the integral over just one spatial mode:
\begin{align}
Z[\phi(k_0)] = \int_0^{2\pi} d \tilde \phi(k_0) \exp \left[i \epsilon_{\mu \nu} k_0^\mu k_0^\nu \tilde \phi(k_0) \phi(k_0)\right]
\end{align}
Since $\tilde \phi$ is periodic, the integral from 0 to $2\pi$ will be the same as the integral from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$ etc., so taking the integral to be over all values of $\tilde \phi$ rather than just $0$ to $2\pi$ just multiplies the partition function by a constant. But the integral over a periodic funciton is the sum over discrete modes which allows us to apply the Poisson summation formula
\begin{align}
    Z[\phi(k_0)] &= \sum_{\tilde \phi_n(k_0)}\exp \left[i \epsilon_{\mu \nu} k_0^\mu k_0^\nu \tilde \phi_n(k_0) \phi(k_0)\right] = \sum_n \delta (\epsilon_{\mu \nu} k_0^\mu k_0^\nu \phi(k_0)-2\pi n)
\end{align}
This is true for every mode $k_0$ so
\begin{align}
    Z[\phi] =  \sum_{n(x) }  \delta(\epsilon_{\mu \nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_\nu \phi- 2\pi n(x))  
\end{align}
In other words, the integral imposes the constraint that $\frac 1 {2\pi }\text d ^2 \phi \in   \mathbb  Z$ locally which means that its integral will also be in $ \mathbb Z$.

While I think this results is what Tong is pointing to in his notes, there are still a few points I'm unsure about. First, the above analysis only holds if $\phi$ is well defined but it is exactly at the vorticies where $n \ne 0$ that it isn't well defined. Also, if the theory is on a torus and $\phi$ winds nontrivially then $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi = 0$ everywhere. And, since $\phi$ is well-defined and differentiable everywhere, by Stokes theorem the integral over the whole space also vanishes: $\int_T \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi = 0 $. However, if we choose a path along the torus, it is still the case that $\oint dx_\mu \partial_\mu \phi \in \mathbb Z $. So in this picture the fact that (1) $\text d^2 \phi$ vanishes everywhere and (2)  the winding number is quanitzed are seperate statements.